# Dialog flow default response set to follow-up no

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to dialog flow and was trying to build a conversational chatbot. The following is the example I'm working with.[image: decison tree]
I created an intent "Q1" with question 1 as the user input. Later, I added a follow up yes and no intent for "Q1". When I test it, though it gives the correct answer for yes and no, I noticed that when I enter "thank you" after asking question 1, I get the output intent as Q1-no. Is there an explanation why the default is Q1-no instead of small talk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialogflow `follow-up intent for NO` has default `user says` added as `thanks but no` & so when you enter `Thank you`, it matches it with `user says` in intents, compute a threshold & check how much percent it matches with a user-entered query. If it is higher than the threshold value you have set in your agent's ML settings, then it gives response for that intent. The solution to your problem is either disable ML from `follow-up intent for NO` or remove `thanks but no` user expression from that intent.

snap-1
[image]
snap-2
[image]
snap-3
[image]
snap-4: Output: Follow-up intent is not called after I removed `thanks but no` user expression.
[image]

Comment: I deleted the user says option and modified the ML threshold value, but it still points to follow-up-no intent. It worked fine when I disabled ML, is it a good practice to disable ML?

Comment: Please read my answer again. You either have to remove `thanks but no` user expression from that list or disable ML for that intent. Both solutions have worked for me. Ideally deciding if disabling ML is a good practice depends on business use case. When disabling ML from that intent, intent will be called only when user entered query exactly matches with user expressions entered in that intent but you can not always assure user will enter exactly that query only.